# Trouble trying to scrape paginated links using Scrapy

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

I'm trying to learn Scrapy by fetching title of entries on a property website with pagination. I'm not able fetch the entries from the 'Next' pages defined in the `rules` list.

Code:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from property.items import PropertyItem
import re

class VivastreetSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'viva'
    allowed_domains = ['http://chennai.vivastreet.co.in/']
    start_urls = ['http://chennai.vivastreet.co.in/rent+chennai/']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ('//*[text()[contains(., "Next")]]')), callback = 'parse_item', follow = True)
        ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        a = Selector(response).xpath('//a[contains(@id, "vs-detail-link")]/text()').extract()
        i = 1
        for b in a:
            print('testtttttttttttttt ' + str(i) + '\n' + str(b))
            i += 1
        item = PropertyItem()
        item['title'] = a[0]
        yield item
```

Edit- Replaced parse method with parse_item and can't scrape anything now.

Ignore the item object code at the end, I intend to replace it with a request callback to another method which fetches more details from the URL of each entry.

I shall post the log if required.

Edit #2- I fetched the URLs from the paginated pages and then yield a request to another method which finally fetches details from each entry's page. The `parse_start_url()` method is working but the `parse_item method()` is not being called.

Code:

```
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from property.items import PropertyItem
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')  #To prevent UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError.

class VivastreetSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'viva'
    allowed_domains = ['chennai.vivastreet.co.in']
    start_urls = ['http://chennai.vivastreet.co.in/rent+chennai/']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = '//*[text()[contains(., "Next")]]'), callback = 'parse_start_url', follow = True)
        ]   

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        urls = Selector(response).xpath('//a[contains(@id, "vs-detail-link")][@href]').extract()    
        print('test0000000000000000000' + str(urls[0]))
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url = url, callback = self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #item = PropertyItem()
        a = Selector(response).xpath('//*h1[@class = "kiwii-font-xlarge kiwii-margin-none"').extract()
        print('test tttttttttttttttttt ' + str(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that are wrong with your spider.

1. Your `allowed_domains` is broken, if you inspect your spider you probably get a lot of filtered out requests.
2. You misunderstand [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawlspider) a bit here. First of all when CrawlSpider starts it downloads every url in `start_urls` and calls `parse_start_url`.

So your spider should look something like:

```
class VivastreetSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['chennai.vivastreet.co.in']
    start_urls = ['http://chennai.vivastreet.co.in/rent+chennai/']
    rules = [
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
        restrict_xpaths='//*[text()[contains(., "Next")]]'),
        callback='parse_start_url'
    )
    ]

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        a = Selector(response).xpath('//a[contains(@id, "vs-detail-link")]/text()').extract()
        return {'test': len(a)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got that part working but I call another method to parse details from urls fetches from that page which doesn't seem to work. What am I getting wrong? Edited the question.